WinSDK compatibility: Which version can I target for?
I am currently developing a Windows app in MSVC2022 (C++20) which links to a few third-party DLLs. I ran into a compiler problem in an exotic Windows header recently:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\oaidl.h(487): error C2059: syntax error: '/'

See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/older-winsdk-headers-are-incompatible-with-zcprepr/1593479. The solution is to upgrade the project to a newer WinSDK. Was using 10.0.17763.0 before, have to upgrade to at least 10.0.19xxx to allow successful compilation.
I tried to find out more about the versions of WinSDK on various sources of the internet, but the information is kinda vague.
What are the implications of upgrading to a newer WinSDK in terms of running it on an older Windows 10?
Does the Windows 10 running my app need to have at least the same version as the WinSDK?
Do I need to build all parts of the Windows app incl. the third-party DLLs with the same WinSDK version?
